# Possible for a ERC-20 contract owner to freeze tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

Is it possible for the contract owner of a ERC-20 token contract to freeze tokens in a third party’s ethereum address?

Sounds stupid, but our project member decided to send a small amount of tokens to an unknown address, which is now out of our control.

Thanks in advance

——

Would it be possible for the contract owner to update the token contract to include a specific burn() function to burn the tokens held in a specific address? ( does burn() allow such?)

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not have control over the address, the tokens have been lost.

If your contract does not have a burn function, unfortunately you can not update it. Perhaps what can be done is to create a new contract that copies the current contract state and includes the burn function, but I do not know if this is so simple for your case.